# What is a word that is like a little treasure you leave for someone else to discover?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am having trouble coming up with a noun that is almost like an Easter egg. Is there any word that could be something someone intentionally leaves for another person to find at a later time?

Comment: You could call it an *"Easter egg"*.

Comment: What about: Hidden gifts!!

Comment: you might be able to shoehorn the word *cache* for this purpose.

Comment: When this is done in computer programs, the term _is_ “Easter egg” as @PeterShor suggests. I’ve seen the phrase used for in-jokes slipped into books or movies, but they are usually termed “shout-outs” to their referents; I don’t know another term used when this hidden joke is not a reference. What is the context you’re looking for a word within?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I'm trying to come up with a name for my app.

Comment: If the app is (for example) a game in which you hide things for someone else to find, “hidden treasure” or “Easter egg” may well be the best phrases to use. (Do you prefer pirates’ caches, or bunnies’?)

Comment: @Ischessinger Successful app names do not necessarily have to aptly describe their products; more importantly, they should be catchy and easy to remember. I wonder if thinking of Easter egg metaphors would be helpful, such as the names of historical treasures and relics or elusive insects and animals? You could also consider wordplay, such as Easter Legs, if you're trying to find hidden legs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A] word that could be something someone intentionally leaves for another person to find at a later time

- treasure (as in buried)
- prize
- discovery (at first not such good match; but ...)
- gift
- galleon (as in treasure ship)

Also, check synonyms of all the suggestions you get.

Drawing a longer bow

- inheritance
- rainbow (as in rainbow's end)

TAFN

Answer (score 1):

A gem is the only commonly known word for a hidden treasure. However, people in Europe and in the Mideteranian countries will recognize (truffle) as a good word for your app.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terfeziaceae

Answer (score 0):

Gem is the most obvious answer I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following: hidden message, cryptic code (or crypt), cipher, secret, puzzle, inside joke, [Cicada 3301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicada_3301) (if you're up-to-date with Internet culture), and the Lost Ark (if you're an Indiana Jones fan).

EDIT: For your app name, here are some ideas by playing with the phrase "Easter egg":

- Easter Leggs!
- Easter Feaster!
- Easter Teaser